# Stack trace bug aggregation software

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, stack-trace

I develop mobile applications for a variety of platforms, notably iPhone and Android.

Each of these applications has a way to "phone home" with fatal crash stack traces.  Up to now, we've been inspecting these by hand as needed.

What I'm looking for is a piece of software that can somewhat accurately "aggregate" or "coalesce" all these stack traces into bug reports.  Output format doesn't really matter, I'm sure we can pipe it into our bug tracker.

So if we get 1000 stack traces that represent the same bug, it would create one ticket even if their stacks vary slightly.

It would be nice if there was a package that was capable of handling stack traces from a variety of platforms (iphone/android/etc), but if not I'd like recommendations for specific platforms too.

Thanks

Comment: check out Flurry: http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/technical-info.html

Comment: We use flurry--it doesn't do this.  It gives you the last line of each stack trace reported, and doesn't aggregate them.  EDIT - That aside, we'd like to integrate directly into our own system, on our own servers.

Comment: Doug - interested in how you get stack traces reported back.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and answer this to close it out, since it's unlikely anyone is wandering along.

What we ended up doing is rolling our own solution.  Basically, we take the last line of the stack trace, and use that as the collapse key.  This line is generally pretty stable, while the rest of the trace can vary pretty wildly.

There are occasionally minor variations, so one optimization we've been considering is using a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of 5 or 6 to determine uniqueness.